# fb feeds showing last 20 posts only

Tags: jquery, facebook, json, rss, feed

My feeds [URL](https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json) in JSON format.but i see only last 20 post.how i get my all post using json format ?

Comment: it shows me 28 entries, first is title: "Doers Inc's Facebook Wall",
updated: "2012-12-19T22:26:23-08:00",
and last one is title: " In software engineering, the term software architectural style generally refers...",
updated: "2012-12-13T16:58:59+00:00"

Comment: but i have so many posts ...why we can't get all posts using json

Comment: Register as developer and use their API URL instead

Comment: i build a system using jsonp with yahoo query language.doers.lk check this out the in the bottom of the page...now my site is automatically updated when i add content to the fb..but i want to get all post from start date of the page.is there any way ?

Comment: See you cant get all post directly, you have to use fb graph api for this. FB changes their policy frequently so you may need to register as fb developer, goto fb developer site and look for fb graph api, thats the only option for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://graph.facebook.com/397319800348866/feed?limit=100 (or whatever number you want) for getting this. Unfortunately facebook changed it so you will need an access token to do this. Which is easyly obtained by fetching https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET

There is a good tutorial on the whole process here: https://illuminatikarate.com/blog/facebook-graph-api-requires-access-token-for-feed-access/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use gaph.facebook.com for this and add the ?limit=25 or what you want it to be.

Comment: i build a system using jsonp with yahoo query language.http://www.doers.lk/ check this out the in the borrom of the page...now my site is automatically updated when i add conetent to the fb..but i want to get all post from start date of the page.is there any way ?

Comment: You must use their api if you want to do that.